# I want to convert these loops to recursive.Is there a way to convert these loops to a recursive

Tags: c++, recursion

I have used 4 nested loop. I want to convert these loops to recursive. Is there a  way to convert these loop into recursive?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
       for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
       {
               for(int t=0;t<2;t++)
               {
                       for(int p=0;p<2;p++)
                       {
                                cout<<i<<k<<t<<p<<endl;
                       }
                }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Probably. Did you give it a go?

Comment: As is the answer to your question is: Yes (however that's too short for an actual answer)

Comment: It could be done, but does not look a very good candidate for recursion. Why do you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware that your question is about converting your pyramid (nested) loops into a recursive function (bad idea due to potential stack overflow), but the code you have presented shows a truth table.

Is that what you are after?

If so, there's a much simpler way to accomplish the same result using bitwise `>>` shifts and the bitwise `&` operator.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++ )
    {
        bool a = ( i >> 3 ) & true;
        bool b = ( i >> 2 ) & true;
        bool c = ( i >> 1 ) & true;
        bool d = ( i >> 0 ) & true;

        std::cout << a << b << c <<  d << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Online code example: https://rextester.com/YAKJL54176

And there's an even simpler way (@Jarod42) if you use the `std::bitset` library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 16; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::bitset<4>(i) << "\n";
    }
}
```

The results are the same as above.

Online code example: https://rextester.com/VBKO8875

Comment: There is even `std::bitset`(as we don't have `std::bin` manipulator) [Demo](https://ideone.com/5NtSGq).

Comment: @Jarod42: So much simpler! I wasn't aware of this. Thanks! I'll add it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like:

```
void foo_rec(int i, int k, int t, int p)
{
    std::cout << i << k << t << p << std::endl;
    if (++p == 2) {
        p = 0;
        if (++t == 2) {
            t = 0;
            if (++k == 2) {
                k = 0;
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
    if (i < 2) {
        foo_rec(i, k, t, p);
    }
}

void foo()
{
    foo_rec(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/jS9zkN)

Comment: I cannot find the words to sufficiently strongly express how much you should not use code like this. Oh wait I just did

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: About code to not use, I could still use goto to avoid recursive call ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't say this is good programming practice, but it's currently the best answer to the question. And we don't know the intent of the OP. It might be a hypothetical question, or a simplified example of a different use case...

Comment: @Jarod42, `goto`?? Haha, I could even implement this with `setjmp()` It even looks quite nice actually (but just for fun of course) ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Hah, true! Let's see it ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `s/    std::cout/start:    std::cout/` and `s/foo_rec(i, k, t, p)/goto start/`. (viewing code with patches :) ) BTW, it is mostly one step way to build the recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

You can but it is a very contrived example that shouldn't actually be recursive. You need to think about how to do it - one recursive function for the whole lot or a couple of smaller ones?

If you go with one recursive function for the whole lot then be aware of your stack size. Here it is 2^4 or 16 levels deep. That's probably ok, but what if `k` needs to be 0..100  instead of 0..1 ?

P.S. to backup my point: Code in the original question is much clearer than the code provided in the other 2 answers. I have no doubt they work, but if you don't have to think about them for a few seconds to figure out what they are doing then you're doing better than me ;-)

Comment: *"I have no doubt they work"*. You should, both first tries had typo

Comment: @Jarod42 I was trying to be nice ;-) But yeah, both failed horribly which goes to show recursion is hard... Have you looked up recursion in the dictionary? `Recursion (n): See recursion`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to convert these loop into recursive?

I do not know of an automated mechanism ... but since your nested-for-loops post is reasonably simple, the manual conversion is straight forward.

Perhaps you are looking for a 'pattern' guide?  So how does a simple recursive loop look?

You have tagged this post as C++, so here my offering uses functors, which are a simplified class's.  These functor's use compiler provided ctor and dtor defaults, which do nothing (quickly).

Below, in the functor "Functor_TailRecursion_t", each for-loop of the post has been replaced with a recursive function, the name of which reflects the for loop var from the post original.  Thus "void r_k(){...}" performs the "for(int k=0;k<2;k++){...} loop.

- Note that each of the 'Functor' functions pass no parameters ... except the hidden 'this' parameter.  This reduces automatic memory use during deep recursions (of which this example has none.)
- Note that the recursive 'Functor' functions are all tail recursion.  The compiler can optimize tail-recursion to iterative performance, though I have not tested on this code.
- Remember that although the compiler is able to in-line small-class-functions, the recursive calls will prevent that from happening.

Good luck on your effort.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using std::cout, std::endl, std::flush;

 #ifndef                 DTB_PCKLRT_HH
 #include "../../bag/src/dtb_pclkrt.hh"
 using DTB::PClk_t;
 #endif


 // postfunction (extracted from main)
 void function_NestedForLoops()
 {
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
       for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
       {
          for(int t=0;t<2;t++)
          {
             for(int p=0;p<2;p++)
             {
                cout<<i<<k<<t<<p<<endl;
             }
          }
       }
    }
 } // void function_NestedForLoops()


 // functor, tail recursion
 class Functor_TailRecursion_t
 {
    int i {0}, k {0}, t {0}, p {0};  // value-initialization
 public:
    void operator()() { r_i(); }     // enter recursion

 private:
    void r_i() { if (!(i < 2)) { i = 0; return; } r_k();  ++i;  r_i(); }

    void r_k() { if (!(k < 2)) { k = 0; return; } r_t();  ++k;  r_k(); }

    void r_t() { if (!(t < 2)) { t = 0; return; } r_p();  ++t;  r_t(); }

    void r_p() { if (!(p < 2)) { p = 0; return; } show(); ++p;  r_p(); }

    void show() { cout << "\n  " << i << k << t << p << flush; };
 }; // class Functor_TailRecursion_t



 class F808_t // ctor and dtor: compiler provided (do-nothing) defaults
 {
    PClk_t  pclk; // posix clock access
 public:
    int  operator()()
       {
          int retVal = 0;
          uint64_t start_ns = pclk.ns();

          cout << "\n\nfunction, nested for loops:\n";
          function_NestedForLoops();

          cout << "\n  functor, tail recursion: ";
          Functor_TailRecursion_t()();

          auto  duration_ns = pclk.ns() - start_ns;
          cout << "\n\n  F808_t::operator()() duration   " << duration_ns
               << " ns    (" <<  __cplusplus  << ")" << std::endl;
          return retVal;
       }

 }; // class F808_t


 int main(int, char**) { return F808_t()(); }
```